# solution of $\nabla^2 \phi = K\phi \nabla^2 \frac{1}{\phi}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Is there any known analytical solution to the below equation?
$\nabla^2 \phi = K\phi \nabla^2 \frac{1}{\phi}$, where $K$ is a constant.
Assume spherical co-ordinates and spherical symmetry, i.e.,
$\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} r^2 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$.
In case there is no analytical solution, is there an asymptotic solution? i.e. for large r?

Comment: $\phi=$ constant is a solution.

Comment: Another remark: if $\phi$ is a non-constant solution to the PDE, then $K^2/\phi$ also is.

Comment: the solutions satisfy $r\left(\phi^2-K^2-\lambda \phi +2K\phi \ln \phi \right)/R = \phi$ for integration constants $R, \ \lambda$

Comment: @Sal, do you have any reference on how to arrive at the solution?

Comment: That equation is equidimensional in $r$; i.e. invariant under a rescaling $r\rightarrow ar$. According to my copy of Bender and Orszag, the substitutions $r=e^{t}$ and $r\,\frac{d}{dr}=\frac{d}{dt}$ will reduce it to an autonomous equation.

Comment: Are there boundary conditions, or for that matter a specific domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $r=x$. We can write the ODE as

$$
x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\cdot x\,\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right]
=-K\phi\,x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x}{\phi^2}\cdot x\,\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right]
$$

Substituting $x=e^t,x\,\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}$ results in, after simplification

$$
\phi''+\phi'=-K\left[\frac{\phi'\phi+\phi''\phi-2\phi'^2}{\phi^2}\right]
$$

where all derivatives are taken with respect to $t$. This in an autonomous equation in $\phi$ (ie. there are no explicit appearences of the independent variable $t$). Further substituting $\phi'(t)=\xi(\phi),\phi''=\xi\xi'$ results in, after simplification

$$
\xi'-\frac{2K\xi}{\phi^2+K\phi}=-1
$$

which is a first-order linear ODE in $\xi$ with the integrating factor

$$
\exp{\left[2\ln\left(\frac{K+\phi}{\phi}\right)\right]}
=\left(\frac{K+\phi}{\phi}\right)^{\!2}
\equiv f(\phi)
$$

Thus the linear ODE becomes

$$
\frac{d}{d\phi}\left[\xi f(\phi)\right]=-f(\phi)
\implies
\phi'\,f(\phi)=-\int d\phi' f(\phi')
\implies
\frac{f(\phi)}{\int d\phi'f(\phi')}\,d\phi=-dt
$$

after replacing $\xi=\phi'$. Performing the trailing integration and changing variables back to $t=\ln{x}$ gives

$$
\int d\phi' f(\phi')=\frac{c_1}{x}
$$

for some constant of integration $c_1$. The integral over $f$ is straightforward:

$$
\begin{align}
\int f(\phi)\,d\phi
=\int\left(\frac{K^2}{\phi^2}+\frac{2K}{\phi}+1\right)d\phi
=-\frac{K^2}{\phi}+2K\ln|\phi|+\phi+c_2
\end{align}
$$

Hence

$$
-\frac{K^2}{\phi}+2K\ln{|\phi|}+\phi=\frac{c_1}{x}+c_2
$$

which has the symmetry property noted by @Goncalo in the comments. Out of curiosity, where did you find this ODE? Did you just make it up, or did it arise in a physical problem?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Does the solution mean that there are no negative values of $\phi$ possible? For negative values, $ln(\phi)$ becomes complex.

Comment: This was an old assignment problem, which I was revisiting.

Comment: @Angela There's no problem with negative $\phi$ -- I just forgot the absolute value bars in the final answer. Nice catch!

Comment: can you point me to the Wolfram page?

Comment: @Angela There's no real need for Wolfram - I added the integration to my post.